# How to customize django group model

Tags: python, django

I want to change django default User and Group model relation from ManyToMany to OneToOne.But I don't know 
the right way to do this.I tried like this but the user field clashes

> roles.Role.user: (models.E006) The field 'user' clashes with the field
>   'user' from model 'auth.group'

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

.
models.py

```
class Role(Group):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: You can't. Create your own model without subclassing the Django `Group`.